# UiAutomator check view visibility

Tags: android, ui-testing, android-uiautomator

I am trying to perform click(or many clicks) on view if it visible on screen. I want smth like this, but there is no `obj.isVisible()` method.

```
UiObject obj = device.findObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("ru.litres.android:id/container"));
UiObject objTop = device.findObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("ru.litres.android:id/container_top"));
while (obj.isVisible())
     objTop.click();
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `obj.exists()` or `obj.waitForExists(timeout)`

UiObject2 way:

```
UiDevice device = 
UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
while(device.hasObject(By.res("ru.litres.android", "container"))) {
    objTop.click();
}
```

Comment: you can add the source for better understanding

Comment: i tried this, but it didnt work correctly in while(){}

Answer (score 0):

```
UiDevice uiDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
uiDevice.wait(Until.hasObject(By.res("ru.litres.android", "container")), 3000L);
UiObject2 objTop = uiDevice.findObject(By.res("ru.litres.android", "container"));
objTop.click();
```